How to compute the predicted response variable after an ANOVA with anova1 in MATLAB?
I want to replicate in MATLAB a simple demo outlined here that uses SAS. The SAS code is
ods rtf file='residual plot SAS output.rtf';
proc print;
run;
proc reg;
model hddt=bloc entry/r p;
output out=new r=residual p=predicted;
run;
proc plot;
plot residual*predicted;
run;
ods rtf close;

(the data follows at the bottom of the post and in the linked pdf)
My MATLAB translation (ignoring output to file):
data = readtable('data.txt', "VariableNamesLine" ,1);
[pw,wtbl,stats] = anova1(data.HDDT,data.BLOC);

I have two issues, one minor and one more relevant to the title:
(1) the analysis seems a simple One-Way ANOVA but the exact output from SAS and MATLAB differ slightly.
SAS (from the demo guide):
Source     SS      df     MS       F     Prob>F
-----------------------------------------------
Groups     1.20463    2   0.6023   0.24   0.7893
Error    220.89537   87   2.53903                
Total    222.10000     89                          

MATLAB:
Source     SS      df     MS       F     Prob>F
-----------------------------------------------
Groups     1.067    2   0.53333   0.21   0.8111
Error    221.033   87   2.54061                
Total    222.1     89                          

This is presumably due to defaults in the treatment of data during F-tests being different in SAS and MATLAB (I don't have access to SAS but have in the past come across discussions of similar issues). I'd like to replicate the SAS output to the extent possible. Any hints on how to would be welcome.
(2) The SAS demo computes predicted values of the response variable (hddt) from the generated model. I don't know how to do this in MATLAB which doesn't appear to provide a similar tool following ANOVAs. The best I could find was the 'predict' function from the 'stats' toolbox eg
ypred = predict(mdl,Xnew);

but is this the best approach and if so what to use as input?
Note that the values of the predicted variable computed in the SAS example don't make sense to me, but I might ask what that is all about at stats.stackexchange:

Thanks for any assistance.
The data (data.txt):
PLOT BLOC ENTRY HDDT HT LODG YIELD MOIST
3501 1 8 32 84.5 3 46.8 21.5
3502 1 30 32 82.5 3 78.9 19.8
3503 1 7 31 73.5 3 68.5 20.7
3504 1 26 36 64.5 1 64.5 16.7
3505 1 13 33 75.5 2 69.8 16.4
3506 1 18 31 76.0 2 74.5 16.7
3507 1 27 31 78.0 2 85.5 18.0
3508 1 4 34 81.5 4 67.3 16.4
3509 1 29 30 72.0 2 77.4 16.2
3510 1 19 30 80.5 2 55.5 15.3
3511 1 23 34 70.0 4 68.4 15.0
3512 1 5 33 85.0 5 64.2 13.8
3513 1 2 32 87.0 4 71.2 14.7
3514 1 22 35 79.0 4 62.0 13.3
3515 1 25 36 89.5 4 66.0 14.8
3516 1 6 31 83.0 2 77.3 13.6
3517 1 17 33 83.5 3 99.4 16.6
3518 1 3 32 84.0 3 79.9 16.2
3519 1 24 33 82.5 1 83.1 18.0
3520 1 21 32 80.5 1 84.1 19.4
3521 1 20 31 80.5 2 81.5 19.6
3522 1 16 31 75.5 1 65.1 16.0
3523 1 1 32 88.0 3 67.3 19.4
3524 1 14 33 82.0 2 72.9 18.5
3525 1 28 31 79.5 1 89.9 20.6
3526 1 10 31 85.0 3 82.6 20.8
3527 1 11 31 89.0 2 70.0 16.1
3528 1 15 33 75.5 1 77.3 18.9
3529 1 9 33 79.0 2 82.5 16.1
3530 1 12 32 105.0 2 57.4 16.2
3531 2 23 34 72.0 5 69.7 16.5
3532 2 8 32 88.5 3 79.7 16.4
3533 2 28 31 81.0 1 87.6 16.0
3534 2 6 32 81.5 2 70.3 15.8
3535 2 18 30 81.0 2 74.6 13.7
3536 2 2 33 84.5 3 70.7 15.3
3537 2 20 31 86.5 5 79.5 16.6
3538 2 9 32 79.5 3 80.0 13.4
3539 2 13 33 79.0 2 68.7 14.6
3540 2 27 31 73.5 3 78.2 15.4
3541 2 30 32 82.5 2 74.7 16.4
3542 2 21 33 77.0 2 72.5 16.1
3543 2 25 35 84.0 2 72.6 16.0
3544 2 12 32 93.5 3 60.1 16.0
3545 2 16 31 69.5 3 65.2 15.8
3546 2 29 30 72.5 1 82.7 18.4
3547 2 17 33 82.5 4 79.1 17.1
3548 2 14 33 80.0 2 74.5 19.4
3549 2 10 32 76.5 2 81.4 17.2
3550 2 26 36 66.5 1 50.7 22.6
3551 2 5 33 80.0 2 52.9 22.8
3552 2 7 32 77.0 2 75.1 21.3
3553 2 15 33 76.0 1 67.2 19.5
3554 2 24 33 86.5 4 77.9 18.3
3555 2 19 30 84.0 3 72.7 15.9
3556 2 3 33 85.0 3 73.9 17.4
3557 2 1 33 87.0 4 70.6 18.3
3558 2 4 34 86.0 5 70.1 16.0
3559 2 22 35 81.5 6 57.4 16.2
3560 2 11 31 92.0 3 63.3 15.1
3561 3 21 32 83.0 2 83.0 15.6
3562 3 22 34 85.0 6 56.6 13.7
3563 3 14 33 85.0 4 83.9 14.7
3564 3 7 32 86.5 4 80.6 15.5
3565 3 27 31 82.0 2 96.5 14.8
3566 3 6 32 82.5 2 70.4 15.6
3567 3 26 37 73.0 1 72.4 16.2
3568 3 4 35 85.0 4 80.1 16.0
3569 3 25 37 88.5 3 77.6 16.0
3570 3 9 33 88.0 2 80.5 15.6
3571 3 2 32 83.5 2 79.5 16.6
3572 3 16 31 73.5 1 70.0 16.1
3573 3 24 33 83.5 3 85.7 17.8
3574 3 18 31 82.5 2 73.9 17.4
3575 3 10 32 85.5 3 95.7 17.7
3576 3 15 33 78.5 2 78.8 19.9
3577 3 23 35 76.0 5 74.4 19.5
3578 3 17 33 82.0 3 77.3 18.9
3579 3 13 33 77.5 2 72.4 16.2
3580 3 1 33 92.0 4 67.4 16.2
3581 3 30 32 86.0 4 86.5 19.4
3582 3 28 32 75.5 2 89.4 16.7
3583 3 29 30 76.5 1 72.2 19.3
3584 3 11 31 86.5 2 55.6 15.2
3585 3 5 33 80.5 3 63.0 15.5
3586 3 8 32 79.5 3 74.2 14.1
3587 3 12 32 103.0 2 60.9 14.9
3588 3 3 33 83.0 3 72.9 15.7
3589 3 19 30 83.5 3 76.8 14.1
3590 3 20 30 89.0 4 80.4 15.7


Use anova instead of anova1. The call to anova1 is equivalent to
aov = anova(data.HDDT,data.BLOC)

or even to
hddt = data.HDDT;
blocks = data.BLOC;
y = [hddt(blocks==1) hddt(blocks==2) hddt(blocks==3)];
aov = anova(y)

The following works too
aov = anova(data(:,{'BLOC','HDDT'}),'HDDT')

as does
aov = anova(data(:,{'BLOC','HDDT'}),'HDDT~BLOC');

All of the above return a convenient structure with more information about the analysis than does anova1, including the residuals, which can be inspected with
aov.Residuals

and are equal to (eg for the first level of the factor)
hddt(blocks==1)-mean(hddt(blocks==1))

The ANOVA terms can be computed "by hand" as follows:
SqDiffG = size(y,1)*(mean(y)-mean(y(:))).^2;
SS_Groups = sum(SqDiffG(:))
SqDiffE = (y-ones(size(y,1),1)*mean(y)).^2
SSE = sum(SqDiffE(:))
SqDiffT = (y-mean(y(:))).^2;
SS_Total = sum(SqDiffT(:));

The difference from the SAS result is presumably because the SAS script applied a linear regression, not ANOVA.
